# running PM2 on windows server using classic azure pipeline

Tags: node.js, windows, next.js, azure-devops, pm2

I am trying to build release pipeline using classic azure pipelines for nextjs project to deploy it on self hosted windows server and I used iis as a redirection server to the nextjs application, my issue is how can I keep the nextjs application running to enable redirection to it from iis?

- I tried npm run start in CMD and it keeps the release pipeline running
- I tried iisnode and it cause errors
- I tried using PM2/ PM2-runtime and it keeps the release pipeline in running state .

tasks which I used

```
 steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Use Node 20.x'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 20.x
    steps:
- powershell: |
   npm i
  workingDirectory: 'some directory'
  displayName: 'npm i'

steps:
- powershell: |
   npm install pm2 -g
   
  workingDirectory: 'some directory'
  displayName: 'npm install pm2 -g'

steps:
- powershell: 'pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production'
  workingDirectory: 'some directory'
  displayName: 'pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production'
  env:
    HOME: ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same situation when using the same pm2-runtime start command.

The Pipeline will keep running after the app starting.

[image]

As far as I know, pm2-runtime designed for Docker container which keeps an application in the foreground which keep the container running,

pm2 is designed for normal usage where you send or run the application in the background.

To solve this issue, you can change to use the pm2 command for the react.js app on windows:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production --watch
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

To avoid the Finalize job clean the process, you can set the variable: `process.clean = false` in Release Pipeline

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: for this solution there is an issue related to the pipeline clean the process so it end the pm2 process. may be I need to add "post-job" task like that you added at the end of the job

the Finalize job result is

Comment: ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2023-12-26T02:03:11.4976075Z Cleaning up task key
2023-12-26T02:03:11.4978351Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2023-12-26T02:03:11.5186395Z Terminate orphan process: pid (4248) (node)
2023-12-26T02:03:11.5353744Z Terminate orphan process: pid (8180) (node)
2023-12-26T02:03:11.5355976Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job

Comment: @MohamedSayed I can understand your issue. Let me check it.

Comment: @MohamedSayed To avoid the clean step, you can add the variable `process.clean = false` check my update.